# Is the mini-profiler left on purpose?

Tags: bug, data-explorer

I visited the site http://data.stackexchange.com to do some study and found that this site uses mini-profiler. I believe devs generally use it when the app is in test/development mode. So was wondering if the mini-profiler was left like that on purpose or it was not taken care of while deploying to prod?

[image: screenshot using firebug]

Comment: I believe it's left on so logs of particularly long queries can be examined.  Plus I don't think the site is used all that much, so leaving it on doesn't impact things much, while it does provide some useful information for users of the site.

Comment: It's been there as long as I've been using the Data Explorer. I don't see how it's harming anything since the Data Explorer is open source. Even kind of nice to see that it's still polling for long running queries.